# Saving Data in a Repeater to a Database in SQL in a Single Row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, repeater

I'm facing a minor problem in ASP.NET. I will explain in detail below.

- I am saving the products in the tbl_ShopCart to the tbl_Order.
- There can be more than 1 product, because I use repeater for shop cart.
- For example: My shop cart have 2 products and I push button to complete shopping and I have saved the data for the tbl_Order. But the total price is recorded separately for the two products. And I want to show the total price in one line for two or more products.

[image]
My design code:

```html
<table class="table shop-cart text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first"></th>
            <th class="text-left text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 text-small black-text">Product Name</th>
            <th class="text-left text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 text-small black-text">Price</th>
            <th class="text-left text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 text-small black-text">Piece</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblShopCartID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("shopcartid") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productid") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <td class="product-thumbnail text-left"><asp:Image ID="ImgProductImage" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="150px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("productimage") %>' /></td>
                    <td class="text-left"><asp:Label ID="LblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productname") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td class="text-left"><asp:Label ID="LblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("price") %>'></asp:Label> TL</td>
                    <td class="product-subtotal text-left"><asp:Label ID="LblPiece" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("piece") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aytasarimConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_ShopCart] WHERE ([userid] = @userid)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" SessionField="userid" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table cart-total">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="padding-two text-right no-padding-right text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 text-small xs-no-padding">Shop Cart Total: </th>
            <td class="padding-two text-uppercase text-right no-padding-right font-weight-600 black-text xs-no-padding"><asp:Label ID="LblShopCartTotal" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label> ₺</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="padding-two text-right no-padding-right text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 text-small xs-no-padding">Cargo Price: </th>
            <td class="padding-two text-uppercase text-right no-padding-right font-weight-600 black-text text-small xs-no-padding"><asp:Label ID="LblCargoPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> ₺</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <th class="padding-two text-uppercase text-right no-padding-right font-weight-600 text-large xs-no-padding">Last Total: </th>
            <td class="padding-two text-uppercase text-right no-padding-right font-weight-600 black-text text-large no-letter-spacing xs-no-padding"><asp:Label ID="LblTotalPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> ₺</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View on browser:
[image]
My aspx.cs code:

```
protected void BtnCompleteOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if(item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label lblproductid = (Label)item.FindControl("LblProductID");
            Image imgproductimage = (Image)item.FindControl("ImgProductImage");
            Label lblproductname = (Label)item.FindControl("LblProductName");
            Label lblprice = (Label)item.FindControl("LblPrice");
            Label lblpiece = (Label)item.FindControl("LblPiece");
            function.cmd("INSERT INTO tbl_Order(userid, productid, name, surname, email, identificationnumber, phone, productimage, productname, piece, cargo, totalprice, paymenttype, orderdate) VALUES('" + Session["userid"] + "', '" + lblproductid.Text + "', '" + Session["name"] + "', '" + Session["surname"] + "', '" + Session["email"] + "', '" + Session["identificationnumber"] + "', '" + Session["phone"] + "', '" + imgproductimage.ImageUrl + "', '" + lblproductname.Text + "', '" + lblpiece.Text + "', '" + Session["cargo"] + "', '" + LblTotalPrice.Text + "', '" + DrpDwnPaymentType.Text + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')");
        }
    }
}

// I add the cargo price on top of the total price, which gives us the lasttotal.
decimal total = 0;
decimal lasttotal = 0;
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView item = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
    total += Convert.ToDecimal(item["price"]) * Convert.ToDecimal(item["piece"]);
    LblShopCartTotal.Text = total.ToString();

    lasttotal = total + Convert.ToDecimal(LblCargo.Text);
    LblTotalPrice.Text = lasttotal.ToString();
}
```

How can I show the total price in one line for two or more products? Any ideas?

Comment: You want one row in the database per product (per order), with the total price if there was more than one of the same product? **Or**, you want every product stored separately, but where there are multiple products of the same kind, they should all show the total price?

Comment: Actually I want to show the total price of the orders that the user has given in one place. Orders may appear line by line. Is this possible?

Comment: What should be the values in those rows? Can you explain with an example

Comment: For example, I am a customer. I added 5 sweaters, 5 shoes in my shop cart and the total price of these two is 500. I want to save these two different products in different lines but I want to show / keep the total price in one place. Is this possible or do you have any other suggestions, how can i make the most logical?

Comment: You want something like:
product 1 - $10.00;
product 1 - $10.00;
Total product 1 - $20.00;
product 2 - $5.00;
Total - $25.00;

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: In the database, it makes no sense to store sub-totals (because that is what we are talking about). Either, store one record for each product, with an item-price and a quantity (default = 1). Or, store one record for every item, with the item-price. Either way, you can then select and group the prices in any way you want afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you. Then is there a way to save the data in a single line in repeater with sql query?

Comment: Ok, in the repeating group you will have 10 lines (using your example). Each line (assuming that one sweater costs $50 and one pair of shoes costs $50) will show a price of $50. Correct? And then you want to add another line at the end of the repeating group which shows the total ($500). This can be done. The $500 will not be added to the database, but will be calculated based on the order-lines (5 sweaters and 5 pairs of shoes) which are stored in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155078/discussion-between-peter-abolins-and-shadouspan).